# My mouse cursor doesn't move and click ubuntu 17.04

Tags: mouse, 17.04

I am new to ubuntu17.04 . I installed alongside windows 10. I didn't have any problem when I was installing it but after installing and restarting, mouse cursor disappears. I make it visible by using `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`. After this mouse moves at first black screen but when desktop loads, mouse stops wherever it is. I tried many ways but those didn't work.

I use :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This works one time but after I use my Windows 10 and return back to Ubuntu that problem returns :( .
How do I fix this?

Comment: Thanks you. See also this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1146689

Answer (score 0):

Type `xinput` in terminal and note down the `id` of your touchpad.

Then type `xinput enable <id>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but IT DOESN'T WORK