# Mouse cursor disappears after I run "sudo apt-get update" on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: updates, mouse, cursor

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop OS.

The mouse cursor disappears after running `sudo apt-get update`

I reinstalled the OS and the cursor was back, but the mouse cursor is gone again after an update in the first start-up.

Without doing an update, lots of software cannot be installed (e.g. R) so I can't avoid it.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here. I'm on a Dell R720 that I've Frankensteined up really well, which makes it a bit of a surprise that the ethernet drivers and mouse are the things that are giving me grief.

I've been trying to fix my ethernet drivers all day and learning how to keyboard navigate. I have the netXtreme2 card 5780 which is also broken by this update and my cheap Amazon USB wifi adapter doesn't play nice with Ubuntu so I'm pulling things over via a USB thumb drive. It's really frustrating because I have a partition with a working Ubuntu Studio 18.04 on the same machine, but I can't find a way to just run an update on the other partition.

I found someone else with same problem (no solution yet): https://superuser.com/questions/1518079/ubuntu-cursor-is-invisible-after-a-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-on-a-dell.

Steps they tried which didn't fix the problem:

- I tried these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
  sudo service lightdm restart
  sudo apt install gdm
  ```
- I tried instructions from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-cGqVLXyrA) (from 2 years ago), which did not fix the problem.
- [This page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824339/mouse-pointer-disappears-in-ubuntu-16-04) says it may be an Nvidia driver issue.
- Someone reported this fixed their problem, but it didn't work for me:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
  ```
- Someone else got temporary relief with this:

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```